# Will too many dependency injected services in ASP.NET 5 controller constructor affect to performance and memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Let's say I have a controller (`UserController`) which contains about 10 actions (`ListUser, GetUserDetail, SearchUser,...`). Each action will use a particular service (one of `IUserListService, IUserDetailService, IUserSearchService,...`). They are dependency injection services which are injected from controller constructor.

The problem is that, for each time my application receive an request (e.g. `/User/ListUser`), the execution passes through the controller constructor and has to wire up all dependent services. I think this is ineffective for memory and performance since it wires up unnecessary services as well instead of wiring up only needed service: `IUserListService`.

1. I'm not sure if my assumption is correct or not?
2. If this is true, is there any effective ways to resolve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-injection-with-fromservices.

Answer (score 3):

Unless something expensive goes on in the constructors of those injected dependencies, the performance impact of those dependencies is trivial. One reason is that in the course of fulfilling requests all sorts of code. That includes middleware and all sorts of other stuff. Constructing those classes isn't a huge part of that.

Maybe some of those dependencies are registered as singletons, so they aren't even getting constructed for each request.

I'm not saying that performance and memory usage absolutely isn't a concern (because I can't know that) but that it's unlikely. But classes that are constructed but never used aren't a big deal. If there are performance/memory issues they'll be in the methods that *do* get executed.

All that being said, it's likely worth breaking up those controllers anyway. If a class has ten injected dependencies and ten methods that each use different dependencies, it's not cohesive. Those ten methods are all doing completely different things, so why are they all in one class?

The class is large and probably difficult to maintain. Are there unit tests for the controller? I bet they're in a class that starts with ten mocks. The tests are difficult to read and maintain. The result is that developers will spend more time reading the class and the tests, changes will take longer, and it might result in defects that take time to fix.

I'll make up some numbers to put it in perspective. These probably aren't even close to real.

But suppose constructing the controller takes 3ms and reducing those dependencies means it takes 2ms, so you've saved 1ms. Multiply that times a millions requests and you've saved 17 minutes of processing time spread out across those million requests where they aren't noticeable. From that perspective it might not matter.

On the other hand (still making this up) splitting up the controller might cost an hour to two and then prevent twice that in additional time spent reading it, increased time to maintain it, extra hours to fix defects, and the massive cost of those defects. That's a better reason to break up the class.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Hannen, Although this does not affect much to memory/performance, I still think it's not good to wire up unnecessary services (let's say they have Transient lifecycle).  Beside splitting controller, do you think we have other ways to deal with it? (In case we must keep all user actions in same UserController)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a controller with more than 4 or 5 interfaces you should check the business logic. There are times when it is necessary to have them but most of the time not, in order to develop a more readable, isolated, maintainable and structured code.
In the case of your example if all interfaces are related to User, you should have a single interface with all user related functionality in it.
Performance is usually slow when handling large amounts of data. For example, if you bring the data of the database users and that data requires many joins of tables, and then there is business logic that manipulates that data in memory can be slow.
My recommendation is that you review your code to make it as concise as possible following SOLID principles and use a performance checking tool to check the timing of your requests. For example Miniprofiler.

This information may help you:
https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/

Comment: Thanks @Facundo,
Actually, if you combining many interfaces into single one, probably, you violate the "I" in the SOLID.

Comment: You are right about that. In your example I was talking about one interface that concentrate all the functions related to User. You shouldn't have one interface per method.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with arguments of @Scott Hannen trying to keep things small en clean
Id addition to this I can suggest 3 options:

1. Low resource overhead a bit more text overhead:

   ```
   private IUserDetailService? _userDetailService;
   private IUserDetailService UserDetailService 
   {
       get
       {
           return _userDetailService ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserDetailService>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. A bit more overhead to create Lazy instances in constructor:

> ```
> _userDetailService = new Lazy<IUserDetailService>(() => HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserDetailService>());
> ```

3. If it is one place that you use the service, you cant just ask DI

> ```
> HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserDetailService>().DoTheUserTHing()
> ```